# how to add i18n tag via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

```
var self = this, names = [], labels = [], classes = [];



var checkboxDefs = {
    checkboxesNames:  names,
    checkboxesLabels: labels,
    checkboxesClasses: classes
};



  function addCheckBox(name, label, htmlClass){
        names.push(name);
        labels.push(label);
        classes.push(htmlClass);
    }

    addCheckBox("power", "Power");
```

this function works.  so, i try to add i18n tag for the purpose of translation

what i did

```
  function addCheckBox(name, label, htmlClass){
        names.push(name);
        labels.push(label);
        classes.push(htmlClass);
        this.attr(i18n,name);
    }
```

But it shows me an error. saying that attr is not defined ....................
I do not know why this.attr(tag, something) works on other scripts.

Comment: Where is the variable `i18n` defined?  Otherwise you are missing the quotes around that attr string name.  Also `attr` is a jQuery method so if `this` is not a jQuery object, that's not going to work.

Comment: thanks...is var self = this, a JQuery Object ? just means this element

Comment: I am unable to tell with the logic you have provided in the question.  You'll need to research that, and potentially change it to `$(this)`.

Comment: In jQuery, `this` is **not** the jQuery object. That's why you use `$(this)` to access jQuery methods. Typically (in jQuery) `this` is a DOM element but it can also be a method (function), depending on context. And what's been posted above was stripped off context. `this` can be anything from window object to a DOM element to a function. You should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: You guys are right after i change it to $(this).. it works and there is no bug anymore. however, i18 is not added,,,nothing happen,,maybe i should use another way to add i18n??

Answer (score 0):

"this" can change its value depending on context. make sure the "this" value is the jQuery object you're trying to call the attr method from. "this" could be the addCheckBox function prototype instead of the object you're hoping to access.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp